# Python-twilio api error?

Tags: python, twilio

im using twilio-python and im following this tutorial:
http://readthedocs.org/docs/twilio-python/en/latest/usage/twiml.html?highlight=nest

But when i try this:

```
from twilio import twiml

r = twiml.Response()
r.say("hello")
with r.gather(finishOnKey=4) as g:
    g.say("world")
print str(r)
```

But i get this:

```
AttributeError: __exit__
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems they aren't really compatible with the `with` statement. Try this:

```
from twilio import twiml

r = twiml.Response()
r.say("hello")
g = r.gather(finishOnKey=4)
g.say("world")
print str(r)
```

Here's what I get:

```
>>> from twilio import twiml
>>> 
>>> r = twiml.Response()
>>> r.say("hello")
<twilio.twiml.Say object at 0x1098d05d0>
>>> g = r.gather(finishOnKey=4)
>>> g.say("world")
<twilio.twiml.Say object at 0x1098d0950>
>>> print str(r)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Say>hello</Say><Gather finishOnKey="4"><Say>world</Say></Gather></Response>
```

Comment: Please see Rob's answer below detailing their fix.

Answer (score 2):

Emmet - good catch.

Matt - pitch perfect response.

We've just pushed a fix for this issue with 3.3.2 - you can pick it up off PyPi or at the GitHub repo here:

https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python

Just update your module and the documented approach will work.  Please shoot an email to the address in my profile - you guys just earned a Twilio T-shirt. :)